# iOS:I set my static tableView separator to none, can I set my separator in my cell all alone？

Tags: ios, uitableview

I set my `static` `tableView`'s separator to `none`, can I set my `separator` in my cell all alone?

In the storyboar I set `separator` to `none`
[image: In the storyboar I set <code>separator</code> to <code>none</code>]

This is the result of set `separator` to `none`, How can I add line under the cell?
[image: This is the result of set <code>separator</code> to <code>none</code>, How can I add line under the cell?]

If I set separator to `Single Line`, there is double line above the red button
[image: If I set separator to <code>Single Line</code>, there is double line above the red button]

Comment: It's your red "退出" button a table footer view? cell separator view is a 0.5 height line. And you can use the `UITableViewCell`'s property `separatorInset` to make sure separator line's leading and trailing space. But I don't think it a good idea to draw separator line by yourself.

Comment: I guess the red button is another cell in a new section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set separator to none.Then draw a line in the cell which need a line.

```
UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, cellHeight - 1 / [UIScreen mainScreen].scale, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 1 / [UIScreen mainScreen].scale)];
// (1 / [UIScreen mainScreen].scale) : 1px width line.
lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self addSubview:lineView];
```